# How to view impersonation requests or queries executed while impersonated

Tags: sql-server, impersonation

I'm trying to debug an issue with getting a Tableau server to make requests to a SQL server Database using `Impersonate via server Run As account`.

I'm now attempting to track the request to see the point of failure.

Is there a way to view all impersonation requests being made to a SQL server and/or queries executed while the requesting user is impersonating another?

Comment: If Tableau uses Windows impersonation for the Run As account, then SQL Server wouldn't know anything about it.

Comment: I've created a temporary VM with a sql server on it and directed my requests to it. In its event viewer I can see a request made by the Tableau server account user with `Impersonation Level: Impersonation`. I assume that somewhere there is a query similar to `REVERT; EXECUTE AS User = @user;` where `@user` is equal to the user making the request to the Tableau server. I'm curious as to where I can see this query if it exists. Using event viewer can I see the user that the login user is impersonating?

Comment: No it's not a query. Windows Authentication works by using Kerberos/NTLM to get a ticket from the DC (or a hash from a non-AD server), which it can then pass on to other services to authenticate. If impersonation is used then I don't think you can tell from the SQL Server side. That `Impersonation Level` is defined as *"The server can impersonate the client's security context on the local system"*, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/impersonation-levels, which just means that the *server* can impersonate the client, not that the client itself is impersonating

Comment: @Charlieface I've found the query and the issue. To impersonate the user must first connect to the DB stating that they are impersonating another user that way the DB can identify if the user has the right to impersonate the user and proceed with the request. I've posted the found query where it does this.

Comment: Yes, you can track `EXECUTE AS` once the client connected. What you can't track is the client originally connecting under an Windows user impersonation context. I guess it's a different question I was trying to answer altogether

Comment: @Charlieface I've temporarily added an image to my answer post. Would you be able to expand your idea with relation to this image. I've spent hours on this and I would like to absorb as much as I can, this is not a sarcastic request.

Comment: It's not related at all: that `Impersonation Level` is related to the Kerberos ticket or NTLM hash, and what the server can do with it. It is not related to `EXECUTE AS` at all. So I think you should just remove it. All it says is that the server can impersonate the client while doing anything on its local machine. If you check that link you will see the other options. `Impersonation Level: Impersonation` does not help you, because you would see that anyway, even without `EXECUTE AS`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239792/discussion-between-mandelbrotter-and-charlieface).

Answer (score 0):

Using SSMS > Object Explorer > Server > Management > Extended Events > [Right Click] Sessions > New Session

As is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) let me find the query

[image]

It seems that tableau server is trying to impersonate the user with their e-mail and not their windows login.

Comment: I would have thought there would have been a separate XEvent for it, but can't find it